# Windows 8 can't run Registry file via Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-8, registry

I'm trying to run a registry file silently in Windows 8 64 bit via the code given below in batch file but it doesn't work and when I run the registry file manually it works fine! Also note that it's working in Windows 7 and Windows XP! I just go this error after I installed Windows 8 64 Bit!

```
       @echo off
       regedit /s abc.reg
```

This is how I run the registry file via batch file! Let me know if anyone can solve this issue!

P.S: I've tried running the batch file with Admin Privileges but no luck!

Comment: Did you run your file with admin permissions?

Comment: @npocmaka yes I did and it didn't run! I believe that the registry file is not being run perfectly as it used to be on Other OS that I tried. Check it yourself.

Comment: When you start a script with admin permissions it starts in `system32`.Try to set `cd "%~dp0"` in the beggining

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue by locating to the Path of the file.

```
    @echo off
    SET myPath="%CD%\abc.reg"
    regedit /s %myPath%
```

Comment: %CD% did not work for me. Not sure if you are running your script from a file share but I am. Instead of %CD% I used %~dp0 and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it by using
window + r --> regedit
Navigate to this location : "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.BAT\"
And Delete "UserChoice" key

Answer (score 0):

For windows 8 you can change the registry key values as shown below.

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.bat]
@="batfile"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.bat\PersistentHandler]
@="{5e941d80-bf96-11cd-b579-08002b30bfeb}"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\open\command]
@="\"%1\" %*"

**Note:** Deleting the "UserChoice" from "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts.BAT\"  works mainly in windows 7. You might not even find the .bat in FileExts for windows 8